# Mongo db date with nullified time stamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a set of documents which I am trying to query on date, my date stored in db is: `08/20/2016 02:03:18 PM`. I am trying to query records on todays date i.e, current date. I tried with following query

```
db.test.find({ "submitDate": { "$gte": new Date() } })
```

I guess `new Date()` takes the current timestamp and doesn't return me any records and `lte` returns all the records which are less than or equal to current timestamp.

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
db.test.find({ "submitDate": { "$gte": new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>"+"T00:00:00") } })
```

This doesnt work for me . I want to query on the current date with time stamp as 0's. Can some body help me out on this.

Comment: Is your date stored as a string in the db with the format `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS PM`?

Comment: No its not stored as string, it is stored as date itself.

Comment: When you do `db.test.findOne()` in mongo shell, is the `submitDate` field displayed as `ISODate("2016-08-20T02:03:18.123Z")` or `"08/20/2016 02:03:18 PM"`?

Comment: When i do findOne i get this submitDate: 08/20/2016 02:03:18 PM (+0530)

Comment: Even though you insist the field is stored as a date, the above says otherwise. [**`Dates`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) in MongoDB are stored internally as a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970) but mongo shell wrap objects of `Date` type with the **`ISODate`** helper; however, the objects remain of type `Date`. In your case I think the dates are stored as strings with that format hence why the query fails when compared with actual date objects.